# Visual Studio 2010 built-in fake/test data generator for SQL Server

Tags: .net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I few months back I attended a Microsoft EnergizeIT seminar where they were showing some of the capabilities of their latest development products. One of the things they had shown that really caught my eye was a built in mock data generator tool to generate mass amounts of fake data from a few seed lists. I don't remember the name of the tool they used and was hoping to try it out. I recall it being part of VS Team Foundation; if anyone knows what I'm talking about and has some links to it and/or documentation, I'd greatly appreciate it. Or for that matter, something similar would be great too.

Comment: Apex has a tool to generate data: https://www.apexsql.com/sql-tools-generate.aspx or https://www.devart.com/dbforge/sql/data-generator/