# Mock Entity Framework database

Tags: c#, database, entity-framework, mocking

I am using Entity Framework 4+.

Is it possible to automatically create some MOCK database from the schema with some random data? Where ints, put ints, where strings, put some GUIDs or whatever...

It would help me to debug my application a lot.

Thank you, James

Answer (score 2):

I discovered [this great tool](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/a850e686-df08-4245-b0bb-5872654285c9/) for use with EF 4 for mocking the database. Basically it is just a T4 template that creates both the "normal" EF layer and also creates a mock object and interface that can be used to test. More documentation [here](http://blogofrab.blogspot.com/2010/08/maintenance-free-mocking-for-unit.html?showComment=1358315551200#c7633419312813596491).

One caveat, though. Out of the box it didn't work for me because my repository code calls SaveChanges() and other methods which are not implemented in the generated interface. I was able to get around this by extracting the interface from Microsoft's ObjectContext implementation and creating my own IObjectContext interface. I then created a base class (for the mock) that implements this interface by simply delegating each of the calls to an injected mock. This way I can use Moq to create that piece in my test class, while still retaining the ability to track inserts, updates, and deletes in the generated mock.

Here are my changes to the "Context" T4 template to fix this issue. Sorry for doing this in little bits and pieces - SO didn't let me post the entire code listing because it was too long.

Add this code before `fileManager.Process();`

```
fileManager.StartNewFile( "IObjectContext.cs");
WriteHeader();
WriteHeaderIncludeSystem();
WriteHeaderIncludeData();
WriteHeaderIncludeContainers();
WriteNamespaceBegin( code, namespaceName );
WriteObjectContextInterface( container, code );
WriteNamespaceEnd( namespaceName );

fileManager.StartNewFile( container.Name + "Mock.ObjectContext.cs");
WriteHeader();
WriteHeaderIncludeSystem();
WriteHeaderIncludeData();
WriteHeaderIncludeContainers();
WriteNamespaceBegin( code, namespaceName );
WriteObjectContextMockBase( container, code );
WriteNamespaceEnd( namespaceName );
```

Add this code after the `WriteInterface()` block.

```
<#+
void WriteObjectContextInterface( EntityContainer container, CodeGenerationTools code )
{
#>
/// <summary>
/// The interface for the generic object context. This contains all of
/// the <code>ObjectContext</code> properties that are implemented in the 
/// concrete ObjectContext class. This interface was created so these members
/// can be mocked, as ObjectContext doesn't have a default public constructor.
/// </summary>
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> interface IObjectContext : IDisposable
{
    void AcceptAllChanges();
    void AddObject(string entitySetName, object entity);
    TEntity ApplyCurrentValues<TEntity>(string entitySetName, TEntity currentEntity) where TEntity : class;
    TEntity ApplyOriginalValues<TEntity>(string entitySetName, TEntity originalEntity) where TEntity : class;
    void ApplyPropertyChanges(string entitySetName, object changed);
    void Attach(System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithKey entity);
    void AttachTo(string entitySetName, object entity);
    int? CommandTimeout { get; set; }
    DbConnection Connection { get; }
    ObjectContextOptions ContextOptions { get; }
    void CreateDatabase();
    string CreateDatabaseScript();
    EntityKey CreateEntityKey(string entitySetName, object entity);
    T CreateObject<T>() where T : class;
    ObjectSet<TEntity> CreateObjectSet<TEntity>() where TEntity : class;
    ObjectSet<TEntity> CreateObjectSet<TEntity>(string entitySetName) where TEntity : class;
    void CreateProxyTypes(IEnumerable<Type> types);
    ObjectQuery<T> CreateQuery<T>(string queryString, params ObjectParameter[] parameters);
    bool DatabaseExists();
    string DefaultContainerName { get; set; }
    void DeleteDatabase();
    void DeleteObject(object entity);
    void Detach(object entity);
    void DetectChanges();
    void Dispose();
    int ExecuteFunction(string functionName, params ObjectParameter[] parameters);
    ObjectResult<TElement> ExecuteFunction<TElement>(string functionName, params ObjectParameter[] parameters);
    ObjectResult<TElement> ExecuteFunction<TElement>(string functionName, MergeOption mergeOption, params ObjectParameter[] parameters);
    int ExecuteStoreCommand(string commandText, params object[] parameters);
    ObjectResult<TElement> ExecuteStoreQuery<TElement>(string commandText, params object[] parameters);
    ObjectResult<TEntity> ExecuteStoreQuery<TEntity>(string commandText, string entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption, params object[] parameters);
    object GetObjectByKey(System.Data.EntityKey key);
    void LoadProperty(object entity, string navigationProperty);
    void LoadProperty(object entity, string navigationProperty, MergeOption mergeOption);
    void LoadProperty<TEntity>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> selector);
    void LoadProperty<TEntity>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> selector, MergeOption mergeOption);
    System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace MetadataWorkspace { get; }
    ObjectStateManager ObjectStateManager { get; }
    void Refresh(RefreshMode refreshMode, IEnumerable collection);
    void Refresh(RefreshMode refreshMode, object entity);
    int SaveChanges();
    int SaveChanges(bool acceptChangesDuringSave);
    int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options);
    ObjectResult<TElement> Translate<TElement>(DbDataReader reader);
    ObjectResult<TEntity> Translate<TEntity>(DbDataReader reader, string entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption);
    bool TryGetObjectByKey(EntityKey key, out object value);
}
<#+
}
#>

<#+
void WriteObjectContextMockBase( EntityContainer container, CodeGenerationTools code )
{
#>
/// <summary>
/// The default concrete implementation of IObjectContext that will be used for mocking. 
/// This contains all of the <code>IObjectContext</code> members that are implemented in the 
/// concrete ObjectContext class. This class was created so these members
/// can be mocked.
/// </summary>
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> abstract class ObjectContextMockBase : IObjectContext
{
    private readonly IObjectContext _objectContext;
    public ObjectContextMockBase(IObjectContext objectContext)
    {
        if (objectContext == null)
            throw new System.ArgumentNullException("objectContext");
        _objectContext = objectContext;
    }

    public virtual void AcceptAllChanges()
    {
        _objectContext.AcceptAllChanges();
    }

    public virtual void AddObject(string entitySetName, object entity)
    {
        _objectContext.AddObject(entitySetName, entity);
    }

    public virtual TEntity ApplyCurrentValues<TEntity>(string entitySetName, TEntity currentEntity) 
        where TEntity : class
    {
        return _objectContext.ApplyCurrentValues<TEntity>(entitySetName, currentEntity);
    }

    public virtual TEntity ApplyOriginalValues<TEntity>(string entitySetName, TEntity originalEntity) 
        where TEntity : class
    {
        return ApplyOriginalValues<TEntity>(entitySetName, originalEntity);
    }

    public virtual void ApplyPropertyChanges(string entitySetName, object changed)
    {
        _objectContext.ApplyPropertyChanges(entitySetName, changed);
    }

    public virtual void Attach(System.Data.Objects.DataClasses.IEntityWithKey entity)
    {
        _objectContext.Attach(entity);
    }

    public virtual void AttachTo(string entitySetName, object entity)
    {
        _objectContext.AttachTo(entitySetName, entity);
    }

    public virtual int? CommandTimeout
    {
        get { return _objectContext.CommandTimeout; }
        set { _objectContext.CommandTimeout = value; }
    }

    public virtual DbConnection Connection 
    { 
        get { return _objectContext.Connection; }
    }

    public virtual ObjectContextOptions ContextOptions
    { 
        get { return _objectContext.ContextOptions; }
    }

    public virtual void CreateDatabase()
    {
        _objectContext.CreateDatabase();
    }

    public virtual string CreateDatabaseScript()
    {
        return _objectContext.CreateDatabaseScript();
    }

    public virtual EntityKey CreateEntityKey(string entitySetName, object entity)
    {
        return _objectContext.CreateEntityKey(entitySetName, entity);
    }

    public virtual T CreateObject<T>() 
        where T : class
    {
        return _objectContext.CreateObject<T>();
    }

    public virtual ObjectSet<TEntity> CreateObjectSet<TEntity>()
        where TEntity : class
    {
        return _objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>();
    }

    public virtual ObjectSet<TEntity> CreateObjectSet<TEntity>(string entitySetName) 
        where TEntity : class
    {
        return _objectContext.CreateObjectSet<TEntity>(entitySetName);
    }

    public virtual void CreateProxyTypes(IEnumerable<Type> types)
    {
        _objectContext.CreateProxyTypes(types);
    }

    public virtual ObjectQuery<T> CreateQuery<T>(string queryString, params ObjectParameter[] parameters)
    {
        return _objectContext.CreateQuery<T>(queryString, parameters);
    }

    public virtual bool DatabaseExists()
    {
        return _objectContext.DatabaseExists();
    }

    public virtual string DefaultContainerName
    {
        get { return _objectContext.DefaultContainerName; }
        set { _objectContext.DefaultContainerName = value; }
    }

    public virtual void DeleteDatabase()
    {
        _objectContext.DeleteDatabase();
    }

    public virtual void DeleteObject(object entity)
    {
        _objectContext.DeleteObject(entity);
    }

    public virtual void Detach(object entity)
    {
        _objectContext.Detach(entity);
    }

    public virtual void DetectChanges()
    {
        _objectContext.DetectChanges();
    }

    public virtual void Dispose()
    {
        _objectContext.Dispose();
    }

    public virtual int ExecuteFunction(string functionName, params ObjectParameter[] parameters)
    {
        return _objectContext.ExecuteFunction(functionName, parameters);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<TElement> ExecuteFunction<TElement>(string functionName, params ObjectParameter[] parameters)
    {
        return _objectContext.ExecuteFunction<TElement>(functionName, parameters);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<TElement> ExecuteFunction<TElement>(string functionName, MergeOption mergeOption, params ObjectParameter[] parameters)
    {
        return _objectContext.ExecuteFunction<TElement>(functionName, mergeOption, parameters);
    }

    public virtual int ExecuteStoreCommand(string commandText, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return _objectContext.ExecuteStoreCommand(commandText, parameters);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<TElement> ExecuteStoreQuery<TElement>(string commandText, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return _objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<TElement>(commandText, parameters);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<TEntity> ExecuteStoreQuery<TEntity>(string commandText, string entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption, params object[] parameters)
    {
        return _objectContext.ExecuteStoreQuery<TEntity>(commandText, entitySetName, mergeOption, parameters);
    }

    public virtual object GetObjectByKey(EntityKey key)
    {
        return _objectContext.GetObjectByKey(key);
    }

    public virtual void LoadProperty(object entity, string navigationProperty)
    {
        _objectContext.LoadProperty(entity, navigationProperty);
    }

    public virtual void LoadProperty(object entity, string navigationProperty, MergeOption mergeOption)
    {
        _objectContext.LoadProperty(entity, navigationProperty, mergeOption);
    }

    public virtual void LoadProperty<TEntity>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> selector)
    {
        _objectContext.LoadProperty<TEntity>(entity, selector);
    }

    public virtual void LoadProperty<TEntity>(TEntity entity, Expression<Func<TEntity, object>> selector, MergeOption mergeOption)
    {
        _objectContext.LoadProperty<TEntity>(entity, selector, mergeOption);
    }

    public virtual System.Data.Metadata.Edm.MetadataWorkspace MetadataWorkspace
    {
        get { return _objectContext.MetadataWorkspace; }
    }

    public virtual ObjectStateManager ObjectStateManager
    {
        get { return _objectContext.ObjectStateManager; }
    }

    public virtual void Refresh(RefreshMode refreshMode, IEnumerable collection)
    {
        _objectContext.Refresh(refreshMode, collection);
    }

    public virtual void Refresh(RefreshMode refreshMode, object entity)
    {
        _objectContext.Refresh(refreshMode, entity);
    }

    public virtual int SaveChanges()
    {
        return _objectContext.SaveChanges();
    }

    public virtual int SaveChanges(bool acceptChangesDuringSave)
    {
        return _objectContext.SaveChanges(acceptChangesDuringSave);
    }

    public virtual int SaveChanges(SaveOptions options)
    {
        return _objectContext.SaveChanges(options);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<TElement> Translate<TElement>(DbDataReader reader)
    {
        return _objectContext.Translate<TElement>(reader);
    }

    public virtual ObjectResult<TEntity> Translate<TEntity>(DbDataReader reader, string entitySetName, MergeOption mergeOption)
    {
        return _objectContext.Translate<TEntity>(reader, entitySetName, mergeOption);
    }

    public virtual bool TryGetObjectByKey(EntityKey key, out object value)
    {
        return _objectContext.TryGetObjectByKey(key, out value);
    }
}
<#+
}
#>
```

Change the first 2 lines (the 2nd one being the curly bracket) of `WriteMockContextBody()` (after the comment) to

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(container)#>Mock : ObjectContextMockBase, I<#=code.Escape(container)#>
{
    public <#=code.Escape(container)#>Mock(IObjectContext objectContext)
        : base(objectContext)
    {
    }
```

Change the first line of `WriteInterface()` (after the comment) to

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(container)#> interface I<#=code.Escape(container)#> : IObjectContext
```

I should also note that I haven't done much testing with this yet, but I did do some basic verifications to ensure it functions.

Comment: Could you paste the file(s) into a gist, and add a link to that?

Answer (score 0):

Here is library that helps in generating test data - http://autopoco.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

See Rab Hallett's blog titled [ADO.NET Mocking Context Generator: Visual Studio 2010 Template](http://blogofrab.blogspot.com/2010/08/mocking-context-generator-visual-studio.html)

Here Rab uses a T4 template to create the interface for EF.

Answer (score -1):

You can check out [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3312130/visual-studio-2010-built-in-fake-test-data-generator-for-sql-server) about Visual Studio for Database Professionals. Or RedGate has a [similar tool](http://www.red-gate.com/products/sql-development/). I don't know of any free tools that would do this.

Comment: Mike, None of your links are related to question. First one maybe.. but... no.